# Passing several arguments for rendering template

Tags: python, django

First of all, let me excuse for my English - it's not my native language.

I have following models:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    student_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    student_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='John Doe')
    dob = models.DateField(max_length=8)

class Group(models.Model):
    group_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    monitor = models.ForeignKey(Student)

class Student_Group(models.Model):
    student_id = models.ForeignKey(Student)
    group_name = models.ForeignKey(Group)
```

I need to render groups of students, its monitors and amount of students in each group. Making first two tasks is not a problem:

**views.py:**

```
def group_list(request):
    groups = Group.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'groups/group_list.html', {'groups': groups})
```

**groups.html**

```
{% for group in groups %}
    <p>{{ group.group_name }}</p>
    <p>{{ group.monitor }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

But when it comes to rendering amount of students for each group, I'm getting stuck.

Following SQL lets to count amount of students in given group

```
select count(*) from students_student
join students_student_group
on students_student.student_id = students_student_group.student_id_id
where students_student_group.group_name_id = "Mega nerds"
```

Questions are:

1. How to get amount of students for each group using Django ORM instead, so the template will render following info:

   - Group name: Mega nerds
   - Amount of students: 8
   - Monitor: John Doe

   ...

   - Group name: Nice guys
   - Amount of students: 11
   - Monitor: John Appleseed
2. How to pass data regarding amount of students to corresponding group.

Thanks.

**Update**

According to @Gocht advice, I used ManyToManyField, so my `models.py` now looks as

```
class Student(models.Model):
    student_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    student_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='Василий Пупкин')
    dob = models.DateField(max_length=8)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.student_name


class Group(models.Model):
    group_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, primary_key=True)
    monitor = models.ForeignKey(Student)
    students = models.ManyToManyField(Student, related_name='students')
```

also, as suggested, I've added decorator to `Group` class:

```
@property
def get_students_qty(self):
    return self.students.all().count()
```

so now I can get number of students in each group, like so:

```
{% for group in groups %}
    <p>{{ group.group_name }}</p>
    <p>{{ group.monitor }}</p>
    <p>{{ group.get_students_qty }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

But I still wondering - is it possible to get number of students in group without using decorator? After all, `Group` class has `students` field...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get the number of students in a group like this:

```
group = ...  # get a group

n_students = Student_Group.objects.filter(group=group).count()
```

Then since every Student_Group object has *one* student, `n_students` will contain the number of student in the given group.

To send this number to your template you can add it in your context:

```
def group_list(request):
    groups = Group.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'groups/group_list.html', {'groups': groups, 'n_students': n_students})
```

You could also see docs for [`ManyToMany`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.10/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships) relationships, that could be helpful here.

**EDIT**

Take some time to check [Python's naming conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions); your `Student_Group` should be `StudentGroup`.

You can create a method in your model to return the number of students in a group:

```
# models.py
class Group(models.Model):

    # fields

    @property
    def get_students_qty(self):
        return self.student_group_set.all().count()
        # Try with self.studentgroup_set.all().count() if the line
        # above does not work
```

then in your template:

```
{% for group in groups %}
    <p>{{ group.group_name }}</p>
    <p>{{ group.monitor }}</p>
    <p>{{ group.get_students_qty }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear regarding what is needed. I've edited my question, please consider to review it, many thanks